# invalid Oracle URL specified: OracleDataSource.makeURL (WAS 8.5)

Tags: java, oracle, websphere, websphere-8, was

I am facing this strange issue in my WAS 8.5, this particular datasource test connection works fine from admin console but in systemout log it throws this error.  The url in my datasource is "jdbc:oracle:thin:@testDb:1521:xyz1", I have tried this format as well but no luck jdbc:oracle:thin:@//testDb:1521/xyz1. Any help on this will be appreciated.

`java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified: OracleDataSource.makeURL DSRA0010E: SQL State = 99999, Error Code = 17,067
  at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.makeURL(OracleDataSource.java:1277)
  at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getURL(OracleDataSource.java:1025)`

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but do you have the data source configured at multiple scopes?  If so, test connection might be testing what is properly configured at one particular scope, whereas at run time, the data source at a different scope might be used, which has its URL misconfigured.  I would recommend checking under all scopes for duplicate definitions of the data source in order to rule this out.

Comment: No duplicate datasources configured, checked that before.

Answer (score 0):

Root Cause Found: It was an OS patch update on WAS servers which was preventing WAS to do any connection to DB and MQ. After reverting that patch everything worked fine.